Norm of Tensor Product of Bounded Linear Functionals
I can't seem to find a citation for this result anywhere except in one paper I am reading, and I don't see how it is true how they have stated it.  Namely, I don't see how the norm estimate is correct.

Let $A,B$ be $C^{*}$-algebras.  Given $\varphi \in A^{*}$ and $\psi \in B^{*}$, there exists a unique bounded linear functional $\varphi \otimes \psi \in (A \otimes B)^{*}$ (the spatial norm) such that $(\varphi \otimes \psi)(a \otimes b) = \varphi(a)\psi(b)$ and $\lVert \varphi \otimes \psi \rVert = \lVert \varphi \rVert \lVert \psi \rVert$.

First of all, this is true for states on $A,B$ respectively, so it's certainly true for any positive linear functionals as well.  Now, if $\varphi,\psi$ are self-adjoint bounded linear functionals then $\varphi = \varphi_{+}-\varphi_{-}$ and $\psi = \psi_{+}-\psi_{-}$ where $\varphi_{\pm}, \psi_{\pm}$ are positive linear functionals importantly with the property that $\lVert \varphi \rVert = \lVert \varphi_{+} \rVert + \lVert \varphi_{-} \rVert$ and similarly for $\psi$ by the Jordan decomposition theorem.
Hence this result holds for all bounded self-adjoint linear functionals without issue.  However if you just assume that $\varphi,\psi$ are any bounded linear functionals, then I only know that $\varphi = \Re(\varphi) + i \Im(\varphi)$ and similarly for $\tau$ where: $$\lVert \varphi \rVert = \lVert \Re(\varphi)\rVert = \lVert \Im(\varphi) \rVert$$ so you get: $$\varphi \otimes \tau := (\Re \varphi) \otimes (\Re \tau) + (i\Im \varphi) \otimes (\Re \tau) + (\Re \varphi) \otimes (i\Im \tau) + (i\Im \varphi) \otimes (i\Im \tau)$$ where you can only conclude that $\lVert \varphi \otimes \tau \rVert \leq 4 \lVert \varphi \rVert \lVert \tau \rVert$.  If I assume momentarily one of the functionals is still self-adjoint (say $\tau$ is, so that $\Re \tau= \tau$), then I can show the result is true.  This allows me to apply that to the above equation to atleast get: $$\lVert \varphi \otimes \tau \rVert = \lVert \varphi \otimes \Re \tau + \varphi \otimes (i\Im \tau)\rVert$$ $$\leq 2\lVert \varphi \rVert \lVert \tau \rVert.$$  However I can't get a better estimate then this in general.  What is the last step to verify this?
ALSO:  An analogous issue I am running into is showing that for $\varphi \in A^{*}$ the slice map $S_{\varphi}: a \otimes b \mapsto \varphi(a)b$ has norm bound $\lVert S_{\varphi} \rVert = \lVert \varphi \rVert$.  I can only seem to show that $\lVert S_{\varphi} \rVert \leq 4\lVert \varphi \rVert$ using that $S_{\varphi} = S_{\Re \varphi} + i S_{\Im \varphi}$ and that $\lVert S_{\psi} \rVert \leq 2 \lVert \psi \rVert$ whenever $\psi$ is a self-adjoint bounded linear functional on $A$.

This follows from polar decomposition of linear functionals. Write $\varphi = u|\varphi|$ and $\tau = v|\tau|$, where $|\varphi|$ is positive and has the same norm as $\varphi$ and similarly $|\tau|$ is positive and has the same norm as $\tau$; and $u, v$ are partial isometries in $A^{\ast\ast}$ and $B^{\ast\ast}$, respectively. Thus, $\varphi \otimes \tau = (u \otimes v)(|\varphi| \otimes |\tau|)$. As $u \otimes v$ is a partial isometry, the norm of $\varphi \otimes \tau$ is bounded above by the norm of $|\varphi| \otimes |\tau|$, which is $\|\varphi\|\|\tau\|$, as $|\varphi|$ and $|\tau|$ are positive.

Do you know a reference where I can read about these polar decompositions?

@Isochron This is in, for example, Section III.4 of Takesaki’s Theory of Operator Algebras I.
